# Multiplicatives

Tags: number-theory

Let $f: N \to N$, $f(2) = 3$, and $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$, that is, f is a multiplicative function. f is also strictly increasing. Show that no such function exists.

Progress: Apparently, this is proven by contradiction.  So I used $f(2) = f(2 * 1) = f(2) * f(1)$.  This gives me $3 = 3 * f(1)$, which means $f(1) = 1$.

I see no contradiction though.  f is strictly increasing, not decreasing, so it makes sense that $f(1) = 1$ but $f(2) = 3$.  Help please?

Comment: Do you mean [multiplicative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function) or [completely multiplicative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_multiplicative_function)?

Comment: The question has been [asked and answered](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154793/nonexistence-of-a-strongly-multiplicative-increasing-function-with-f2-3) before on this site.

Comment: You are correct that you have not found a contradiction.  That does not prove that one does not exist.  It takes going higher in the arguments of $f$ to find it.